# List comprehensions of dictionary values

Tags: python, list, dictionary, list-comprehension

I am new to Python and I am trying to learn manipulating a dictionary. I have a dict that has the following structure:

```
dict = {'city1':([1990, 1991, 1992, 1993],[1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8]),
        'city2':([1993, 1995, 1997, 1999],[2.5,3.6,4.7,5.8])
```

I would like convert the key of in the following way

```
 'city': ([1990, 1.5],[1991, 1.6],[1992,1.7],[1993,1.8])
```

I tried using a for loop to loop through the values and create a new value for each key. However, this seems really slow and clumsy. Is there any Pathonic way of achieving this goal?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This gives you *exactly* the output you want:

```
d = { k : tuple(map(list, zip(*d[k]))) for k in d }
```

Output:

```
{'city2': ([1993, 2.5], [1995, 3.6], [1997, 4.7], [1999, 5.8]), 'city1': ([1990, 1.5], [1991, 1.6], [1992, 1.7], [1993, 1.8])}
```

Also, do consider a different name than `dict` as this is the name of the built-in `dict` class.

---

`zip(*d[k])` is a simplified version of `zip(d[k][0], d[k][1])` but they both do the same thing and generate pairwise tuples.

`map(list, ...)` generates a map object that converts each element in the `zip` to a list (in python2 tuples are automatically converted to lists)

`tuple(...)` converts the `map` list/generator to a tuple of lists, which is exactly what you want.

Comment: Thanks for the explanations of zip()! It makes much more sense to me now.

Answer (score 3):

You can try this:

```
d = {'city1':([1990, 1991, 1992, 1993],[1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8]),
    'city2':([1993, 1995, 1997, 1999],[2.5,3.6,4.7,5.8])}   

new_dict = {a:tuple(map(list, zip(b[0], b[1]))) for a, b in d.items()}
```

Output:

```
{'city2': ([1993, 2.5], [1995, 3.6], [1997, 4.7], [1999, 5.8]), 'city1': ([1990, 1.5], [1991, 1.6], [1992, 1.7], [1993, 1.8])}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! It solves my problem fast and neat.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 3):

You can try the following code

```
a = [[a, b] for a, b in zip(dict['city1'][0], dict['city1'][1])]
```

Output

```
[[1990, 1.5], [1991, 1.6], [1992, 1.7], [1993, 1.8]]
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach would be using this concise solution:

```
res = {k: zip(v[0], v[1]) for k, v in d.items()}
```

**Output:**

```
>>> {k: zip(v[0], v[1]) for k, v in d.items()}
{'city2': [(1993, 2.5), (1995, 3.6), (1997, 4.7), (1999, 5.8)], 'city1': [(1990, 1.5), (1991, 1.6), (1992, 1.7), (1993, 1.8)]}
```

Comment: This will generate *tuples*.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Yes it generates lists of tuples but I think it should also work for OP.

Comment: Very neat solutions! Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1):

I'm just going to throw my answer in, because I haven't seen anyone take advantage of `for key, (year, value)` yet. Which I find quite readable and direct

```
d = {'city1':([1990, 1991, 1992, 1993],[1.5,1.6,1.7,1.8]),
    'city2':([1993, 1995, 1997, 1999],[2.5,3.6,4.7,5.8])} 

a = {k : [list(group) for group in zip(year, val)] for k, (year, val) in d.items()}
```

[image]